Issue in creating calendar events in user timezone using google apps script?
I have a script in a google sheet that creates events in a calendar. The Google sheet time zone is GMT-5 while in the script editor timezone is GMT-4, now the issue is my timezone is GMT+5 when I run this event creation script it does not create an event based on my timezone rather it does it according to google sheet/script timezone.
I am able to get user timezone and convert the startTime and endTime accordingly, Here is the sample script:
 function run() {
    
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var customizeSheet =spreadsheet.getSheetByName("✨ CUSTOMIZE PACE");
  
  var calendarData = customizeSheet.getRange("A2:I2").getDisplayValues()[0];
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  
  var timeZone = getUserTimeZone();
  calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);
  var timeZoneOffset = getTimeZoneOffset(timeZone);

  var eventDate = new Date(calendarData[1]);
  createEventP(calendarData[0],eventDate, calendarData[2], calendarData[4], calendarData[6],calendar,timeZoneOffset)
}

function createEventP(eventName, eventDate, startTime, endTime, eventDescription, calendar,timeZoneOffset) {
 
  var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(eventDate,  "GMT"+timeZoneOffset, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + startTime + ' ' + "GMT"+timeZoneOffset;
  var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(eventDate,  "GMT"+timeZoneOffset, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + endTime + ' ' + "GMT"+timeZoneOffset;
  var options = {
    description: eventDescription
  };
  calendar.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate), options);
}

function getUserTimeZone() {
  var userTimeZone = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getTimeZone();
  return userTimeZone;
}

function getTimeZoneOffset(timeZone) {
  var now = new Date();
  var timeZoneOffset = Utilities.formatDate(now, timeZone, 'Z');
  return timeZoneOffset;
}

The following lines convert to the user timezone:
 var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(eventDate,  "GMT"+timeZoneOffset, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + startTime + ' ' + "GMT"+timeZoneOffset;
 var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(eventDate,  "GMT"+timeZoneOffset, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + endTime + ' ' + "GMT"+timeZoneOffset;

but the issue is with the following line, it converts the user timezone to script timezone again due to the usage of date object new Date():
calendar.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate), options)

Any help to resolve this issue would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

what about using UTC time format?

How would that help?

let me test something real quick. In the meantime, can you clarify if there's any restriction on changing the script timezone? also, will this code be run by other people in different timezones as well?

yes, people from different timezones run this, all get the same timezone instead of as per their own timezone

I think that your showing script occurs an error in calendar.createEvent(eventName, startDate, endDate, options);. Because the values startDate, endDate are required to be the date object. But, you say I am able to get my timezone but the start time and end time of the event in the calendar are not according to my timezone.. So, I'm worried that you might have misplaced your script. How about this?

And, in your question, you say I have set the calendar timezone as well but to no avail.. But, at the bottom of your question, you say I want to create an event based on the User timezone, not on the Spreadsheet/script timezone.. What is your actual expected result? And, in this case of create an event based on the User timezone, how is the user's timezone known? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

thank you for your assistance, I get the user timezone using this: var timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
Then I try to convert the calendar timezone, startTime and endTime of event according to this variable. Basically I want the event to be created in user timezone not according to script/spreadsheet timezone.

The sheet shows startTime (10 AM) and endTime (10 PM), but when script creates an event in the calendar, it shows different event startTime and event endTime. Which is not according to user timezone.

@Tanaike, I have modified my question, please let me know if you need any more information

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. What is the user timezone? I think that in this case, there are 3 timezones of the timezone of Google Apps Script project or the timezone of Google Spreadsheet or the timezone of Google Calendar. Which timezone do you want to use?

And, you can I get the user timezone using this: var timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;. But, in your showing script, this script is not used. So, I'm worried that you might have miscoped your current script. How about this?

yes, you are right. I have modified my script, so please ignore this statement: var timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; 

By user timezone, I mean currently where user is located. The event creation should not depend on spreadsheet/script timezone, rather based on the location of the user. That's why I am using the user's default calendar timezone because it could be the timezone where user is located

Thank you for replying. I understood yes, you are right. I have modified my script, so please ignore this statement: var timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;. About By user timezone, I mean currently where user is located., from your reply That's why I am using the user's default calendar timezone because it could be the timezone where user is located, you want to use the timezone of Calendar. Is my understanding correct?

By the way, when I tested your showing script using your provided Spreadsheet and my Google Calendar, it seems that an event that the start time and end time are 5/16/2024 10:00 AM and 5/16/2024 10:00 PM, respectively, is created as my timezone. Is this different from your expected result?

Ideally, I want to use the user timezone, but I am hoping that we can get the user timezone from the user's default calendar, that's why I used the default calendar to get the timezone. You are right, the event created with the above script shows correct timing but wrapping the time in new Date() object changes its timezone in the following line: calendar.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate), options)

Thank you for replying. About but wrapping the time in new Date() object changes its timezone in the following line: calendar.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate), options), I think that in this case, the timezone of the Google Apps Script project is used. But, when an event is created by those dates, the dates are converted to the timezone of each calendar. Is this situation different from your expected result?

I think you are right, it converts according to the calendar timezone

Thank you for replying. About I think you are right, it converts according to the calendar timezone, in this case, I think that your script can be used without modifying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I would like to respect the existing answer and discussions.

The already posted answer is not correct, it shows an error which I mentioned in the comments of the answer

Thank you for replying. About The already posted answer is not correct, it shows an error which I mentioned in the comments of the answer, when you test your showing script in your question, isn't it your expected result?

In Google Sheets, datetimes and durations are stored as dateserial values. When you read the value in a date, time, datetime or duration cell in Apps Script, the dateserial is automatically converted to a JavaScript Date object.
From the documentation:

A JavaScript date is fundamentally specified as the time in milliseconds that has elapsed since the epoch, which is defined as the midnight at the beginning of January 1, 1970, UTC (equivalent to the UNIX epoch). This timestamp is timezone-agnostic and uniquely defines an instant in history.

So perhaps no conversions are needed in the first place. Just use Range.getValues() instead of Range.getDisplayValues() to get Date objects instead of strings that look like dates. Try something like this:
function run() {
  const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('...put ID here...');
  if (!calendar) throw new Error('Cannot find calendar by that ID.');
  const eventData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getRange('✨ CUSTOMIZE PACE!A2:I2')
    .getValues()
    .flat();
  createEventP(calendar, eventData);
}

function createEventP(calendar, eventData) {
  const [eventName, eventDate, startTime, unused, endTime, eventDescription] = eventData;
  const startMoment = new Date(eventDate.getTime() + startTime.getTime());
  const endMoment = new Date(eventDate.getTime() + endTime.getTime());
  calendar.createEvent(eventName, startMoment, endMoment, { description: eventDescription });
}

See these resources:

Working with date and time values in Google Sheets

Working with Dates and Times in Apps Script

How to parse RFC3339 to field.



it shows the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createEvent')

you forgot to add () in SpreadsheetApp.getActive

I will accept it if it answers my question.

@EagleEye the error you quote indicates that there is no calendar by the ID you specified.
